# Category theory in context ex.4.2.ii : Adjunction induces equivalence on full sub category where unit and count are natural isomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory

Exercise 4.2.ii from Riehl's category theory in context is as follows:

> Prove that any pair of adjoint functors $F: C \rightleftharpoons D$ restrict to define an equivalence between the full subcategories spanned by those objects $c \in C$ and $d \in D$ for which the components of the unit $\eta_c$ and of the counit $\varepsilon_d$, respectively, are isomorphisms.

I'm a little confused on what it suffices to show.
Denote by $C'$ and $D'$ the full subcategories defined in the question. I think one of the following should be enough but I'm not sure which:

- $F(C')=D'$ and $G(D')=C'$.
- The restriction of $F$ to $C'$ essentially surjects onto $D'$ and restriction of $G$ to $D'$ essentially surjects onto $C'$.

I've made some attempt at the first one: If $\eta_c$ is an isomorphism, then $F(\eta_c)$ is an isomorphism. I think it should be true that $F(\eta_c)=\varepsilon_{F(c)}$?

What does it suffice to show? And how can we show that?

Comment: Look at the triangle identities in Definition 4.2.5 and evaluate them at objects. Then use that if in a commutative triangle two of the maps are isomorpisms then also the third one is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing this 2-out-of-3 property! However I am still confused on which condition we need to check. If $F: C \rightarrow D$ is a functor, this induces $F\vert_{C'}: C' \rightarrow D$ for $C'$ any subcategory of $C$. We can refine this to $F\vert_{C'}: C' \rightarrow F(C')$. In general do we need to check that $F(C')=D'$ or something weaker with essential subjectivity?

Comment: As FSrike already wrote, you only need to show that for $c \in C'$ one has $F(c) \in D'$ and that for $d\in D'$ one has $G(d)\in C'$.  Then the restrictions will be an equivalence between C' and D' because they will satisfy the condition of Definition 1.5.4.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define $F'=F|_{C'}:C'\to D'$, you need to show that if $\varsigma\in C'$ then $F(\varsigma)\in D'$. Dually you need to check that $G'=G|_{D'}:D'\to C'$ makes sense.

But, given this, the natural transformations $\eta,\epsilon$ will then sensibly restrict to: $1_{C'}\implies G'F'$ and $F'G'\implies 1_{D'}$. Since they are then isomorphisms, you've already met the definition for an equivalence.

So you only have to check $F',G'$ are well-defined, really.